# Bus error (core dumped) with matplotlib pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, anaconda, pyqt5

Using the IPython console to generate a matplotlib.pyplot chart I only recently get `Bus error (core dumped)`.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I'm using Anaconda Python distribution.

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.get_backend()
Out[2]: u'Qt5Agg'

In [3]: plt.plot(range(10))
Bus error (core dumped)
```

If I use jupyter notebook then `plt.get_backend()` reports `%matplotlib inline` and everything works fine.

So I suspect its Qt5.

I'm stumped as I have tried everything I know. My laptop is an identical setup with Anaconda works fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem!

Install Tk (C++ library) and Tkinter (python wrapper around it) - credit to [Run matplotlib in a virtualenv on Ubuntu 16.04 with different backends - Boris Belousov](http://www.boris-belousov.net/2016/05/16/matplotlib-virtualenv/).

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev python-tk python3-tk
```

Then in `IPython` run

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

This generates a plot window.